# My app freezes or goes black when running a hardware-intensive algorithm

Tags: android, performance

So I am developing an android app for a school project, it allows the user to either take a picture or load an image from the gallery, and then it runs k-means clustering algorithm on the image to output the most dominant colors (https://buzzrobot.com/dominant-colors-in-an-image-using-k-means-clustering-3c7af4622036) However, when the image is chosen the android app either turns to black, or it freezes. I do not know what the error is or how to correct it, and there is no error it seems in the debugger, and I do not know enough about the android platform to have intuition for such a problem. Any help would be much appreciated!

this is the button functions:

```
public void loadFromGallery(View view) {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
}
public void takePhoto(View view){
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

and this is the function called when the photo is returned:
, and the line which calls K-Means is:

```
ArrayList<Point> colors = c.getColors(selectedImage, 4, 10);
```

and as you can probably see, without this line the app works perfectly but with it breaks. The code for this function does work, and occasionally the app will work fine and output the colors, but rarely. Therefore I think this has something to do with a resource limit or a time limit?

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        try {
            final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            //get and shrink bitmap
            final Bitmap selectedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream), 100, 100, true);

            //run kmeans
            ColorFinder c = new ColorFinder();
            ArrayList<Point> colors = c.getColors(selectedImage, 4, 10);
            //colors of points in android color format


            ArrayList<Integer> cs = new ArrayList<Integer>(4);
            for (Point color : colors){
                cs.add(hexToColor(color));
            }
            image.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);

            ColorDrawable drawable1 =  (ColorDrawable) color1.getDrawable();
            drawable1.setColor(cs.get(0));
            textView1.setText(c.RGBtoHex(colors.get(0)));
            ColorDrawable drawable2 = (ColorDrawable)color2.getDrawable();
            drawable2.setColor(cs.get(1));
            textView2.setText(c.RGBtoHex(colors.get(1)));
            ColorDrawable drawable3 = (ColorDrawable)color3.getDrawable();
            drawable3.setColor(cs.get(2));
            textView3.setText(c.RGBtoHex(colors.get(2)));
            ColorDrawable drawable4 = (ColorDrawable)color4.getDrawable();
            drawable4.setColor(cs.get(3));
            textView4.setText(c.RGBtoHex(colors.get(3)));


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "You havent picked image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use AsyncTask or Thread.

Comment: It's a principle that long running task should be done inside a worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing IO operation on your main thread, use asynctask inside your on activity result to get rid of black screen

```
private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String resp;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            //get and shrink bitmap
            final Bitmap selectedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream), 100, 100, true);

            //run kmeans
            ColorFinder c = new ColorFinder();
            ArrayList<Point> colors = c.getColors(selectedImage, 4, 10);
            //colors of points in android color format


            ArrayList<Integer> cs = new ArrayList<Integer>(4);
            for (Point color : colors){
                cs.add(hexToColor(color));
            }
            image.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);




        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        ColorDrawable drawable1 =  (ColorDrawable) color1.getDrawable();
            drawable1.setColor(cs.get(0));
            textView1.setText(c.RGBtoHex(colors.get(0)));
            ColorDrawable drawable2 = (ColorDrawable)color2.getDrawable();
            drawable2.setColor(cs.get(1));
            textView2.setText(c.RGBtoHex(colors.get(1)));
            ColorDrawable drawable3 = (ColorDrawable)color3.getDrawable();
            drawable3.setColor(cs.get(2));
            textView3.setText(c.RGBtoHex(colors.get(2)));
            ColorDrawable drawable4 = (ColorDrawable)color4.getDrawable();
            drawable4.setColor(cs.get(3));
            textView4.setText(c.RGBtoHex(colors.get(3)));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                "ProgressDialog",
                "Loading");
    }
}
```